# How to use LINQ to query for specific object in an array in a list of objects?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects like this:

```
var obj =
[
    {a : [{v:1},{x:1}] },
    {a : [{y:1},{t:2}] },
    {a : [{z:1},{s:3}] }
]
```

I want to select only objects that has a list of elements, and at least one of which has property "x". In this case, I want {a : [{v:1},{x:1}] } to be returned by the LINQ. 
Something like

```
obj.Where(s => 
    foreach(var o in s.a){ 
        if(o.x) return true; 
    }
    return false;
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `.Any()`

```
obj.Where(s => s.a.Any(o => o.x)).ToList());
```